# $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}|x| \cdot \cos{\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|}}$ simple calculation not actual proof required

Tags: calculus, limits

> calculate $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}|x| \cdot \cos{\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|}}$

---

I am trying to figure why it is is equal to zero , in a simple way no need for a proof just limit properties or a use heine series theorem

$\cos{\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|}}$ does not exist because it will be $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\cos{\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|}}=\cos{\infty}$
but $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}|x|=0$

I believe it is equal to zero because "zero limit $\cdot$ bounded limit=0"

or because $\lim _\limits{n \to \infty} |a_n|=0 \iff \lim _\limits{n \to \infty} a_n=0 $

since then we will get $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}|x| \cdot |\cos{\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|}}|= \lim_\limits{x \to 0}|x| \cdot 1 =0$

but I am not sure if I can use that here as $x \to 0$ and not $\infty$

thanks for any tips and help

Comment: Do you know Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: Hint: $|\cos\theta|\le 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|\cos({\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|})}|$ $\le$ 1
then $-|x|$ $\le$ $|x|\cos({\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|})}$ $\le$ $|x|$.Hence
by the squeeze theorem ,as $x \to 0$ ,$|x|\cos({\frac{x-5}{|x^2-x|})} \to 0$